# how to align CSS box in center of the screen?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to set the login box centre of the screen
but because of `position: absolute` background colour changes to white.

```css
/* all */

.patua_font {
    font-family: 'Patua One', cursive;
}

.Roboto_font {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


/* login css */

.cus_body {
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #31E89F, #00aff4); /*this has no effect after setting position absolute in box*/
}

.btn-primary.custom-btn {
    background-color: #00bcd4;
    border-color: #31E89F;
    width: 100%;
}

.center1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.cus_loginpad {
    padding: 4% 7%;
}

.box {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 390px;
    height: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 45%;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin: 10px;
}

.box input {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 4px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>sample</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Patua+One&family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="cus_body patua_font">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box ">
            <div class="cus_loginpad ">
                <h2 class="center1"><img src="images/sample.png" width="150" /></h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pwd">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary custom-btn"> Login </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

how I can set background: linear-gradient(to right, #31E89F, #00aff4);
thankyou.

Comment: [Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically/33049198) can be a good solution

Comment: This shows you **ALL** ways on [how to center an element](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)  Use Flexbox or grid for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display: flex` for this. You can also use `display: grid` but to be honest I still prefer flexbox because I have to support IE. If you don't have to support IE go for grid layouts.

Here is a good overview on how to [center any element](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) either horizontally or vertically or both

Here is an example on how to center your box, I expanded the `.container` class here but you can also add another class just for centering this login-box if you don't want all content centered on all your pages.

```css
/* all */

.patua_font {
    font-family: 'Patua One', cursive;
}

.Roboto_font {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


/* login css */

.cus_body {
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #31E89F, #00aff4); /*this has no effect after setting position absolute in box*/
}

.btn-primary.custom-btn {
    background-color: #00bcd4;
    border-color: #31E89F;
    width: 100%;
}

.center1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.cus_loginpad {
    padding: 4% 7%;
}

.box {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 390px;
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    top: 45%;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin: 10px;
}

.box input {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 4px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>sample</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Patua+One&family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="cus_body patua_font">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box ">
            <div class="cus_loginpad ">
                <h2 class="center1"><img src="images/sample.png" width="150" /></h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pwd">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary custom-btn"> Login </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

By making the `.container{display: flex; height:100vh;}` - you can then simply provide `.box{margin: auto;}` to your box and it will center vertically and horizontally.

The following snippet is best viewed in fullscreen mode to view the magic :)

```css
/* all */

.patua_font {
    font-family: 'Patua One', cursive;
}

.Roboto_font {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


/* login css - note I added the container stlying below */
.container {
  display: flex; 
  height: 100vh
}

.cus_body {
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #31E89F, #00aff4); /*this has no effect after setting position absolute in box*/
}

.btn-primary.custom-btn {
    background-color: #00bcd4;
    border-color: #31E89F;
    width: 100%;
}

.center1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.cus_loginpad {
    padding: 4% 7%;
}

.box {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 390px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin:auto; /* note that I added this*/
}

.box input {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 4px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>sample</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Patua+One&family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="cus_body patua_font">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box ">
            <div class="cus_loginpad ">
                <h2 class="center1"><img src="images/sample.png" width="150" /></h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pwd">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary custom-btn"> Login </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as they said above, you need this:

```
.box {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 390px;
    height: auto;

    // You don't need this
    /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* bottom: 50%; */
    /* padding: 20px 20px; */
    
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.cus_body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #31E89F, #00aff4); /*this is now showing */
  
  // You need to position the parent as relative 
  // by centering it this way, it will be responsive by default
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Here is a working example in JSbin:
https://jsbin.com/fomasexala/3/edit?html,css,output